# My website loads to first input form

Tags: html, css

If I go visit my website, the page immediately scrolls to the first input in the contact form page, rather than display at the top of the page. I could probably set the scrollTop in a jquery script to fix it but I would rather get a solution that would work without manipulating the page using jquery or javascript. Can anyone explain this behaviour or how to fix it?

site: http://danmacmill.host22.com/

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Is it fixed already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the autofocus part of that input, and that problem is gone.

Comment: Geeze, thanks. Its strange because it was never doing that before until I put the contact form into an iframe to avoid reloading the entire page after submission.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have `autofocus` on `<input name="name"/>`. Try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will cause you the problem

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" autofocus><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

but if you use it this way it will solve your problem

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Check this out

Answer (score 0):

Remove autofocus property:

```
<span>Name*:</span>

<input name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the autofocus parametter you have on that input. You must remove it or manipulate with js